# How to implement tap status bar to scroll to top for iphones in reactjs

Tags: ios, reactjs, mobile-safari

Some pages on safari don't seem to support the tap status bar to scroll to top of the page feature. Does this need to be added and if so, how do you do that for a react js app? I did a bit of research and it seems like I need to use the UIKit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [React refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).